# Is it possible to compile with -qopt-zmm-usage=high and set only one method to -qopt-zmm-usage=low. Disable Z register in one loop

Tags: intel, icc, avx512, auto-vectorization

Using the intel compiler to compile a class, e.g. `MyClass.h MyClass.cpp`

Using the following compiler flags

`-O3 -qopt-zmm-usage=high`

If the intel compiler heuristics are found to be incorrect for one loop and its performance is actually higher without vectorization then vectorization can be disabled marking the loop with the `#pragma novector` pragma.

Is there an equivalent to only enable `XY` instructions, i.e. to disable the `Z` register?

Comment: If you're using ZMM registers in most loops, it's normally best to let compilers use them in all loops, because you're already paying for the downside of lower turbo frequency (which lasts long enough to cover a whole loop, back to other ZMM code).  But not always, e.g. with misaligned memory or something the compiler does a bad job with, yeah you might be better with `zmm-usage=` something other than high.  IDK how to do that on a per-function basis with ICC pragams or options, though, so just commenting.  Disabling AVX-512 would work but be sub-optimal vs. letting a compiler use AVX-512VL.

Comment: Please experiment with #pragma omp simd vectorlength (N) on the loops of interest.

It should allow to selectively "downshift" ISA to AVX2. In certain versions of Intel Compiler (eg 2 yrs ago) it was also possible to downshift more specifically to AVX512VL.

Unfortunately I don't see any documentation on the topic and I suppose that it was maybe decided to not force it a lot, but rather wait until OpenMP5 evolves (see OMP5 "omp declare variant match"), plus latest Intel server processors became better in terms of avx512 freq throttling.